# How to create groups in odoo 8?

Tags: xml, odoo

I would like to create security group in odoo which comes under USABILITY not under User Roles?

```
<record id="group_custom_chats" model="res.groups">
    <field name="name">Chatting Options</field>
    <field name="category_id" ref="bms.crm_lead_custom"/>
    <field name="users" eval="[(4, ref('base.user_root'))]"/>
</record>
```

the above code results in like below image.

[image]

I want to make it comes under Usability/Other. Can anybody help me out.

Answer (score 2):

You need to set proper category reference for that.

```
<record id="group_custom_chats" model="res.groups">
    <field name="name">Chatting Options</field>
    <field name="category_id" ref="base.module_category_usability"/>
    <field name="users" eval="[(4, ref('base.user_root'))]"/>
</record>
```

You can easily find solution by looking how odoo set groups under which category by searching that groups xml definition.

These groups are defined in base module in **security/base_security.xml** file 
    
       Multi Companies

```
<record model="res.groups" id="group_multi_currency">
   <field name="name">Multi Currencies</field>
</record>
```

And you can see that the category_id has been updated for these groups are in **base/module/module_data.xml**

```
<record model="res.groups" id="group_multi_company">
    <field name="category_id" ref="module_category_usability"/>
</record>

<record model="res.groups" id="group_no_one">
    <field name="category_id" ref="module_category_usability"/>
</record>
```

Answer (score 0):

1 - Go to **Setting** - **Group** and add a **new group**.

2 - Chose the **Usability** as the name of the application and complete other information.

3 - It's Done ;)

I have an example for you:

[image: example]